# C# Interactuando con base de datos

Tags: c#, ms-access, base-de-datos

Estoy empezando con C# VS 2019. Vengo de muchos años felices con VB6 haciendo una aplicación de escritorio para mi propio negocio. Esta interactúa con una BD (access por ahora, migrara a SQL Server) consultando, añadiendo, modificando, eliminando registros,...

El primer problema con el que me topé es que no encuentro nada parecido al objeto recordset de Adodb que había en VB6. Con una conexión, una consulta SQL (tan compleja como quisieras, relacionando varias tablas, consultas anidadas, clausulas join,...) y un objeto recorset tenias control absoluto de la BD. Abrías la conexión, abrías el recordset con la consulta y a operar con los registros. Un metodo update o updatebatch y cambios enviados. Diferentes tipos de recordset, diferentes formas de abrirlo, recordset desconectados,...pero así de fácil.

Lo mas parecido que he encontrado en C# es el uso de los Dataset y los DataTables que incorpore en el, pero son solo tablas, sin vinculación directa con la BD. Si realizas cambios en los DataTables y luego quieres enviarlos a la BD, lo mas fácil que he encontrado es usar un Commandbuilder y el update del Dataset, porque escribir para un form con 20 campos una instrucción Insert o Update (con sus 20 Parameters) puede ser muy tedioso. Usando este sistema (los builders) me he encontrado ahora con el problema de obtener, al insertar un registro nuevo, el campo PK autoincrement del resgistro, cuando en VB6 con los recorset era solo llamar al metodo resync y listo.

La pregunta: ¿Estoy usando la estructura/planteamiento mas correcto para trabajar con una BD y una aplicación de escritorio?

Saludos y gracias

Comment: el dataset se asemeja  a un recordset, pero el dataset puede ser un conjunto de dataTables, te recmiendo leer http://www.elguille.info/NET/ADONET/cadena_de_conexion_para_conectar_a_una_base_de_sql_server.htm yo me cambie desde el 2004 a .net y vb6 lo odio! fue bueno es su época para cosas sencillas

Comment: Que grande el Guille!!!. La conexión no me da problemas, la hago estableciendo la ruta en el app.config y recuperándola de ahí. Gracias¡¡

Answer (score 0):

La forma que describes de programar quedo obsoleta hace muchos años, yo tambien comence con `vb6`, pero hace mucho pase a `c#` y puedo decirte que es miles de veces mejor, lo que sucede que tienes esa resistencia al cambio y aprender algo nuevo, por eso todo lo anterior parece que era mejor.

Si buscas esos `Wizard` magicos que tenias en `vb6` que arrastras y ya tenias el form conectado a la db, debo decirte que ya no existe, vas a tener que codificar.

Lo que recomendaria es que estudies sobre `ado.net`, pero no te quedes con este porque tambien esta quedando atrasado.

Lo ideal es que empieces a evaluar utilizar `Entity Framework`, con un `ORM` puedes mapear entidades con las tablas de la base, indicando como se persisten y como se relacionan/navega las entidades.

Podrias empezar con la doc oficial

[Entity Framework 6](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/)

usa `Code First` asi tendras mayor control sobre el mapping de las entidades

Recuerda que en c# programas orientado a objetos, por los tanto son entidades, no tablas con las que trabajas

Comment: Gracias Leandro. No usaba ningún tipo de controles enlazados en VB6. No tener el control no me gustaba. Todo lo hacia con código y puro ADO, que ya aquella versión me parecía magia lo que hacia en ocasiones. Al pasar a C# empecé mirando EF pero me parecía una capa intermedia y lo deseche. VB6 también tenia un generador de modelos para acceder a la BD y no lo usaba. En C# estoy descubriendo cosas increíbles y un ahorro de código enorme. Investigaré mas en el link que me pasas. Gracias!!!

Comment: Entity Framework es justamente lo que no deberias haber desechado, ya que es lo que se usa actualmente en todos los desarrollos, y no es ninguna capa intermedia de nada, se usa muchisimo los ORM si vinieras del mundo Java alli se usa NHibernate.

Comment: Leandro desde tu mensaje estoy metiéndome en EF core y me parece algo impresionante. Esta claro que malinterprete lo que era. Tengo la base de datos ya creada en access, la voy a ir migrando a sql server tabla a tabla a medida que vaya desarrolando la aplicación en C#. Por eso creo que quizás use el designer en vez de code first. Aún me queda mucho para ver como hacer con EF lo que hacía antes con el modelo antiguo pero realmente es el modelo a usar. Lo usaré con Linq to entities para las consultas y operaciones con las tablas. Parece ser lo más correcto ¿no?. Gracias¡

Comment: Si es el camino correcto, no uses ningun designer con EF es pra problemas, code first te da mas libertad

Answer (score 0):

Adicional a lo que dice @leandroTuttini te recomiendo utilices algo con ado.net y programación a 3 capas.

[programacion-en-3-capas](http://joseluisgarciab.blogspot.com/2014/09/programacion-en-3-capas.html)

Creo que es un mejor planteamiento y organización para trabajar con bd directamente antes de iniciar con un ORM.

Ya que te encontrarás con entender entidades, otras cosillas en tu transición a .net
te recomiendo mire este [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-architecture) para entender dataset y arquitectura ADO

Comment: Interesante el link de programación en 3 capas. Los veré en profundidad.